# c# - While loop coding theory, making a login and register sysem

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have coded a system based of the theory that while loops can work anywhere in a system. So once a while loop has been passed by it can run. Here is a simple version of my code:

```
using System;

namespace test___login
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string location = "homepage";
            while (location.Equals("Homepage", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

            {
                Console.WriteLine("homepage");
                Console.WriteLine("WHere to now: ");
                location = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (location.Equals("login", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("login");
                Console.WriteLine("Where to now: ");
                location = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I assumed that once the variable changes from "login" to "homepage" in the second while loop, would mean the first while loop would run once again. Is my theory on how the code works wrong or am i simply not typing the right thing. I just started last week so sorry for the basic question

Comment: No, you understand it wrong. Loop will not repeat after its finished unless it's somehow called again. You actually just need one loop to repeat asking question with `ReadLine()` inside and `if/switch` to make a choice based on entered value.

Comment: your code reads from top to bottom, once the first `while` statement equates to `false` it will go to the second `while`. so the first `while` will execute until the condition is no longer met, then same can be send for the `second`

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't run again, because the code has already executed past that line so unless you call it again, the next thing down the line will execute, in your case nothing - this is called procedural programming.

Why don't you make one while loop, and a switch statement instead.

```
bool run = true;
while (run)

{
      Console.WriteLine("WHere to now: ");
      string location = Console.ReadLine();

    switch(location.ToLower()){
        case "homepage":
            Console.WriteLine("HomePage");
            break;
        default:
            run = false;
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with the way you have your code currently structured. It will exit the application. You need to surround all of that with one more `while` loop, which can be similar to your other loops. See below:

```
using System;

namespace test___login {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string location = "homepage";
            while (!location.ToUpper().Equals("EXIT"))
            {
                while (location.Equals("Homepage", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("homepage");
                    Console.WriteLine("WHere to now: ");
                    location = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                while (location.Equals("login", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("login");
                    Console.WriteLine("Where to now: ");
                    location = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```